# Couchbase adapter "Sails-cbes" for Sails.js - ORM failed to Load

Tags: node.js, sails.js, couchbase

I am using sails-cbes with sails and couchbase. When I try to lift sails getting below mentioned error

```
error: A hook (orm) failed to load!
error: Error: Failed to connect to the Couchbase/ElasticSearch clients { [Error: failed to connect to bucket] code: 25 }
```

This is my connections.js file

```
  // config/connections.js
  cb: {
    adapter: 'sails-cbes',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8091,
    user: 'Administrator',
    pass: 'word2pass',
    operationTimeout: 60 * 1000, // 60s
    bucket: {
        name: 'default',
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the bucket does not exist on the couchbase cluster when you start the application, as the current implementation does not create it at startup.
You have to do the bucket creation manually, matching the configuration before starting the application.

Also, I don't see any mention of elasticsearch and I have to say it's a necessary component for this setup, as the querying functionality is implemented on top of it. I didn't test this but it probably won't even run without it, failing in a similar fashion.